# How to resolve a namespace error in BlazorServer default project solutions (VisualStudio code)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, namespaces, blazor, blazor-server-side

I've created multiple new BlazorServer projects in vs code using `dotnet new blazorserver` on multiple pcs and I always get this error.

```
The type or namespace name 'Shared' does not exist in the namespace 'BlazorServerTutorial' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [BlazorServerTutorial]
```

Compiles and runs with no problems but its quite annoying to have a constant error showing.

Has anyone else been able to resolve this issue?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkRvt.png)

Comment: Yes, I get that all the time.  I think Intellisense just can't keep up.  I don't have a solution-- people have said a lot of stuff about how to "solve" these issues, but it mostly seems like "jiggle it and hope it works."

Comment: By chance did you delete the `WeatherForecast.cs`. This would cause the error as nothing is in the namespace.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is that the namespace is "inferred" (best word I can think of), i.e. there are Razor files in the *Shared* folder without a `@namespace` entry.  When the Razor compiler builds them into classes the correct namespace information is added.   Visual Studio understands this, but Visual Studio Code obviously doesn't.

The simple fix is to add a `@namespace xxxxxx.Shared` entry to one of the Razor files in *Shared*. VSC then see's the namespace directly and the error message goes away.  It's the same for any directory with Razor files and inferred namespaces.