# vscode Blazor wasm cannot found App namespace how can I fix it?

Tags: visual-studio-code, namespaces, blazor-webassembly

[image: Visual Studio Code]

using vscode can not find App like screenshout.

it can build successfuly. and when I open with visual studio2020 there is no error.

visual studio:
[image: Visual Studio2020]

to MrC aka Shaun Curtis

I added namespace to razor file. but still not work

[image: still not work]

Comment: See my answer to this question.  It's the probable cause. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67947847/how-to-resolve-a-namespace-error-in-blazorserver-default-project-solutions-visu/67957723#67957723

Comment: still not work...

Comment: You need to check your namespace nomenclature.  `WasmClient.Shared` underlined in `using` suggests `Program` can't find the `WasmClient.Shared` namespace.